# Algebraic number signs manipulation in ERB templates

Tags: ruby, erb, algebra

I have an ERB template:

```
<%
a = rand(-10..10)
b = rand(-10..10)
c = rand(-10..10)

%>

The solution of this equation $<%=a%>x + <%=b%> = <%=c%>$ is 

$<%=a%>x = <%=c%> - <%=b%>$
...
```

The problem is that when `b` is negative I get double minus. Example:

```
$2x = 4--2$
# a = 2, b= -2, c= 3, I get
```

Is there a way to avoid that and put `+` instead of `--`

Answer (score 3):

Use an `if` statement:

```
<%= b > 0 ? '-' : '+' %>
```

You might also want to consider doing something different (but I don't know what!) if `b == 0`?

Comment: _"but I don't know what!"_ – maybe `b = rand(1..10).yield_self { |i| [i, -i].sample }` which would exclude zero but allow both, positive and negative values.

Comment: Ensuring that `b != 0` is certainly an option, yes. But if OP did want to include that a valid random selection, then they need to decide how it should be displayed.

Comment: Indeed, and you probably want to handle `a` and `c` being zero, too.

Comment: It's a much wider "problem" than OP makes out. You'd might want to think about the formatting of this line too, if `a` or `b` are negative: `$<%=a%>x + <%=b%> = <%=c%>$`. Also if `a == 0`, then the equation is either meaningless or impossible. Also if `c == 0` then you might want to omit it from line 2.

Comment: Basically unless you want to introduce some "equation formatter" library for the whole thing, it's probably much easier to either accept some slightly odd formatting, or otherwise just ensure `a`, `b` and `c` are all positive.

Comment: Is there any library in ruby (ERB) for algebraic manipulation?

Comment: @TomLord Be kind please. Previously I searched

Answer (score 3):

This would work: (instead of `-b` you could also say `b.abs`)

```
<% if b.negative? -%>
  $<%= a %>x = <%= c %> - <%= -b %>$
<% else -%>
  $<%= a %>x = <%= c %> + <%= b %>$
<% end -%>
```

Or, via string manipulation:

```
$<%= a %>x = <%= "#{c} + #{b}".sub('+ -', '- ') %>$
```

Comment: Yes, but I meant something more algebraic. Without having to discuss the cases with `if` statement. Some library.

Comment: Really, with more complex equations, it is unpractical: too many ifs.